# Angular unit testing doesn't recognise an extension method when used in a very specific place

Tags: angular, unit-testing, compilation, karma-jasmine, extension-methods

While using an already existing project as a POC for unit testing, I encountered a problem at compilation time only when running tests.

I have a couple of `string` extension functions with custom title case and whatnot, but one of these which is meant for removing characters from a string is used in a `string` utilities class, in a method for cleaning up separator characters from document IDs (such as dots and dashes).

This works perfectly when running Angular application, but the Testing API seems to not be able to find it at that point. If the extension method is used directly in the component, it works as expected, so I know it's not a coding issue.

What could I be doing wrong?

The error (which doesn't happen when running the project. Only when running tests):

[image: Error message]

`string-extensions.ts` (only relevant code):

```js
export {};

declare global {
  interface String {
    /**
     * Remove a/s string/s passada/s por parâmetro desta string
     * @param text string/s a ser/em removida/s
     */
    emRemove(...text: string[]): string;
  }
}

String.prototype.emRemove = function(...text: string[]) {
  let retorno = this;
  if (text && text.length > 0) {
    text.forEach(t => {
      retorno = retorno.split(t).join('');
    });
  }
  return retorno;
};
```

`string-utils.ts` (only relevant code):

```js
export default class StringUtils {
  /**
   * Remove caracteres separadores de documentos e retorna somente o código
   * @param documento valor a ser limpo
   */
  static getDocumentoLimpo(documento: string): string {
    if (this.isNotEmpty(documento)) { // this tests undefined, null only whitespace and actual empty string without using the sometimes misleading falsy
      return documento.emRemove('-', '/', '.');
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

Project structure:

[image: Project structure]

Edit:

`angular.json` (only the projects.architect.test part. If more parts are needed, please ask):

```json
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
```

Comment: Can you show your `angular.json` ? Angular uses different parameters when it builds for run or for test... You may have forgotten to add your custom lib to the `scripts` attribute of the test config...

Comment: You should put the same thing as in the other `scripts` fields of the file. But indeed, from what I understand of your code, you add functions in the `string` prototype, so you have to run this code before any other TS code, so yeah, you have to put this file's path in angular.json I guess. Otherwise, I personnaly prefere using Utils classes. So I would do `MyStringUtils.emRemove(myString, '-', '/', '.');`

Comment: @Random, that's the only `scripts` field in this file. Tried `"scripts": [ "src/app/shared/extensions/string-extensions.ts" ]` but didn't work. But you gave me some light. I'll search around this. In case I'm unable to use it, I'll have to end up using the extension function directly in the component instead of using the utils for this functionality.

Comment: How are `string-extensions.ts` and `string-utils.ts` scripts imported in your code ?

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud, via import, but now that you mentioned it, the utils class doesn't have the import even though it works when running normally. Apparently when I use it in a component, it automatically imported the file, but when I used it in the utils class, it didn't. Though adding this import there caused another error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. Edit: usage in another component shows no import either, so I guess it just assumes it is part of `string` and no importation is actually required. It just needs to be compiled before everything

Comment: Can you show component code and tests code with imports ?

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud, I haven't used it in tests yet. I'm still trying to figure out why the testing framework seems to be compiling it in a different order than the normal Angular execution. But the component that has it imported, imports it this way: `import '../../../shared/extensions/string-extensions';`

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by adding the extensions to the "include" part of the tsconfig.spec.json

```json
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    ...
    "include": [
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "**/*.d.ts",
        "**/*.extension.ts",
        ...
    ]
}
```

Given we have the convention to name our extension files `*.extension.ts`

Comment: Jeff, this seems to have solved the issue. I'm having some other errors now, but not the one I had before regarding the extension method. So when I get the time I'll test it out and solve the other issues. For now, you receive my +1. When I get the whole thing to work properly, I mark you as the answer